# I cannot get a colored code with docsify?

Tags: docsify

I am using docsify to build a documentation for my API. However when I insert code block (especially json) the code is written in black.

I don't know how to change it.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

Docsify uses Prism for syntax highlighting as explained in [the Documentation](https://docsify.js.org/#/language-highlight).

To add support for a specific language you need to add the matching grammar file as so :

```html
<!-- Loading Docsify -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify/lib/docsify.min.js"></script>
<!-- Adding json syntax highlighting -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs@1.22/components/prism-json.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to browse the list of grammar files available you can browse them here : [PrismJS on Github](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/tree/master/components)

Answer (score 0):

You must add the scripts ***after*** the docsify js script. If you add them before, you will see an error in the console that says Prism is not defined.

Add them like so:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/docsify/lib/docsify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs@1.28/components/prism-bash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs@1.28/components/prism-typescript.min.js"></script>
```

After that, you can highlight using your new language:

````
```bash
yarn add fast-data-engine
```
````

...and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, at least for PHP,  was to make sure the language files were included before the main prism library.

```
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify@4"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs@1/components/prism-bash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs@1/components/prism-php.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs@1.29.0/prism.min.js"></script>
```